# Create table from query in SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server-ce

How do I save the results of a query in SQL Server Compact to a new table?  In SQL Server I'd use `SELECT ... INTO`, or in MySQL I'd use `CREATE TABLE.. AS`.  What would be the command for SQL Server CE?

Comment: Have you tried the `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: Yes, apparently SELECT INTO is not supported in SQL Server Compact.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using SQL syntax, you would have to use .NET code to do this.

1: Get a DataReader with the result.
2: Use GetSchemaTable info to generate the CREATE TABLE statement
3: Generate Inserts for new table.